# Delphi - Certificate error in TWebBrowser, no error in IE9

Tags: delphi, certificate, twebbrowser

Few years ago I wrote a Delphi app which opens an intranet site in [TWebBrowser](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser). The app works fine on Windows XP SP3, but on Windows 7, TWebBrowser shows the IE8-style red certificate error page. Moreover, clicking on "Continue to this website" doesn't open the page. Interestingly, when I open the page either in IE8 on Windows XP, or in IE9 on Windows 7, it opens successfully, and the browsers report no certificate error.

Is it possible to configure [TWebBrowser](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser) or the application or Windows itself in a way which eliminates the certificate error page?

I've tried to run the app in admin mode, with and without Windows XP compatibility mode. I've installed the certificate of the page into every reasonable cert store. I played with the security settings of IE, and the Internet Explorer [FeatureControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730.aspx) settings in the registry. None of these helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I rewrote my answer after David Heffernan's comments.)

**1. Workaround**

Turning off "Check for server [certificate revocation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/04/07/enabling-certificate-revocation-check-failure-warnings-in-internet-explorer.aspx)" in "Internet Options\Advanced\Security" eliminated the certificate error page in `TWebBrowser`. Note that turning off revocation checking opens a security hole (thanks to David Heffernan for emphasizing this in his comments).

[image: Certificate Revocation Checkbox]

**2. Difference between Windows XP and 7**

The different behavior was due to that [this option is turned off on Windows XP by default](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/04/07/enabling-certificate-revocation-check-failure-warnings-in-internet-explorer.aspx), but on Windows 7 it's turned on. It's strange that this security setting is handled differently on different OS versions. Windows XP should have been patched to turn this setting on by default.

**3. The problem with the certificate**

When revocation checking is turned on, IE reports that there is no problem with the site's certificate and every certificate in the certificate chain is OK. This is misleading, because if the Internet Explorer Feature Control [FEATURE_WARN_ON_SEC_CERT_REV_FAILED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330735.aspx#cert_rev_fail) is also turned on, IE displays a Certificate Warning which says "Internet Explorer was unable to contact the issuer to ensure the certificate has not been revoked".

[image: Certificate Issuer Unreachable]

**4. The effect of Silent Mode**

When revocation checking is turned on, and the issuer cannot be contacted, `TWebBrowser` [shows a Security Alert popup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/04/side-effects-of-setting-the-silent-scripterrorssuppressed-property-for-web-browser-control.aspx) with the text "Revocation information for the security certificate for this site is not available. Do you want to proceed?" Unfortunately, when the `TWebBrowser.Silent` property is `True`, the prompt is suppressed and "No" is automatically chosen. In my case, Silent Mode was turned on because I wanted to hide the JavaScript errors of the page, so `TWebBrowser` jumped directly to the certificate error page, and didn't let me proceed.

[image: Revocation Information Unavailable]

**5. The solution**

The security hole can be avoided by enabling the revocation check, but in this case `TWebBrowser.Silent` must be `False`, and the user will have to close every popup manually (on the above Security Alert popup "Yes" must be clicked). Since my app uses the site automatically (based on code written in PascalScript), it has to close every popup itself (this feature has already been implemented for Confirm popups).

Comment: That doesn't really sound like a solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's why I used the double quotes. There is no problem with the certificate of the site, it's not been revoked. In spite of this, turning off revocation check works.

Comment: You've not solved anything. You don't understand what is going on. You've just buried your head in the sand. Now when you load pages with revoked certs, you'll never find out about it. Your *solution* is akin to disabling your virus scanner because it happened to report one false positive.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK, I replaced the word "solution" with "workaround". I agree this workaround is not a solution, but it works, so I can use it until I understand what's happening. I asked the question because I hope that experts will come up with a real solution eventually, but in the meantime I must do something with the problem. I'm sure you understand the situation.

Comment: It doesn't really work. It's not a workaround. What you've done is opened a security hole.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I figured out what happened and rewrote my answer. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: I wonder if we have the same problem with TChromium? I am migrating all my TWebbrowser based apps to TChromium due to this sort of limitations. Sadly there are still webapps out there that only support IE :(